Coupled quasi-linear PDEs
Is there any way of solving the following coupled PDEs using Mathematica?
$$ \partial_t a(x,t) + \partial_x (a(x,t) u(x,t))=0  $$
$$ \partial_x (a(x,t) |u_x|^{m-1} u_x)=0$$
Initial and boundary conditions are
$$  u(0,t)= exp(-t), $$
$$  a(x,0)= (L_0-x)^b , L_0=L(t=0)=5;  $$
$$ a(L(t),t)= 0, $$
$$ u(L(t),t)= \partial_t L(t)$$
I appreciate it if someone could help.

You have not defined what L(t) is or given a way to determine it. You also did not give value for b. Are these pde's from a real physics problem?

@Nasser L(t) is evolved according to the last equation. It's initial value is 5 (3rd to the last equation).

We can solve this problem using FDM. First we map solution on (0,1) using substitution x=y L[t] as follows
eq = {Derivative[0, 1][a][y, t] - (y*Derivative[1][L][t]*Derivative[1, 0][a][y, t])/L[t] + (1/L[t])*D[a[y, t]*u[y, t], y] == 0, 
    D[a[y, t]*D[u[y, t], y]^m, y] == 0, Derivative[1][L][t] == u[1, t], u[0, t] == Exp[-t], a[y, 0] == (L[0] - L[0]*y)^b, a[1, t] == 0, 
    L[0] == 5}; 

The code is given by
sol[b_, m_] := 
  Module[{tmax = 1, dy = 1/10}, xgrid = Range[0, 1, dy]; 
   nn = Length[xgrid];
          M1 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], xgrid, 
      DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
   vA = Table[va[i][t], {i, nn}]; a1 = M1 . vA;
   vU = Table[vu[i][t], {i, nn}]; u1 = M1 . vU;
   eq1 = D[vA, t] - (L'[t]/L[t]) xgrid  a1 + 1/L[t] M1 . (vA  vU); 
   eq1[[-1]] = vA[[-1]];
   eq2 = M1 . (vA  u1^m);
   eq2[[1]] = vU[[1]] - Exp[-t]; eq3 = {L'[t] - vU[[-1]]};
   ic = Join[vA - (L[0] - L[0] xgrid)^b /. t -> 0, {L[0] - 5}]; 
   var = Join[vA, vU, {L[t]}]; eqs = Join[eq1, eq2, eq3]; 
   s = NDSolve[{Table[eqs[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqs]}], 
      Table[ic[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[ic]}]}, var, {t, 0, tmax}, 
     Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic}]; s[[1]]];

Example of usage
sol11 = sol[1, 1]; 

Visualization
lstA = Table[{{xgrid[[i]], t}, vA[[i]]} /. sol11, {i, 
   Length[xgrid]}, {t, 0, 1, .02}]; a = 
 Interpolation[Flatten[lstA, 1]]; lstU = 
 Table[{{xgrid[[i]] , t}, vU[[i]]} /. sol11, {i, Length[xgrid]}, {t, 
   0, 1, .02}]; u = Interpolation[Flatten[lstU, 1]];

x0[t_] = L[t] /. sol11; xmax = x0[1]

{DensityPlot[
  If[x <= x0[t], a[x/x0[t], t], Nothing], {x, 0, xmax}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}, PlotLabel -> "a", PlotPoints -> 100], 
 DensityPlot[
  If[x <= x0[t], u[x/x0[t], t], Nothing], {x, 0, xmax}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}, PlotLabel -> "u", PlotPoints -> 100], 
 Plot[L[t] /. sol11, {t, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "L"}]}


In a case of $u_x<0, m\ne 1$ this code should be modified as follows
sol[b_, m_] := 
  Module[{tmax = 1, dy = 1/10}, xgrid = Range[0, 1, dy]; 
   nn = Length[xgrid];
   M2 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], xgrid, 
      DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix"; 
   M1 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], xgrid, 
      DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
   vA = Table[va[i][t], {i, nn}]; a1 = M1 . vA;
   vU = Table[vu[i][t], {i, nn}]; u1 = M1 . vU; 
   mu = RealAbs[u1]^(m - 1);
   eq1 = D[vA, t] - (L'[t]/L[t]) xgrid a1 + 1/L[t] M1 . (vA vU); 
   eq1[[-1]] = vA[[-1]];
   eq2 = M1 . (vA mu u1);
   eq2[[1]] = vU[[1]] - Exp[-t]; eq3 = {L'[t] - vU[[-1]]};
   ic = Join[vA - (L[0] - L[0] xgrid)^b /. t -> 0, {L[0] - 5}]; 
   var = Join[vA, vU, {L[t]}]; eqs = Join[eq1, eq2, eq3]; 
   s = NDSolve[{Table[eqs[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqs]}], 
      Table[ic[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[ic]}]}, var, {t, 0, tmax}, 
     Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic}]; s[[1]]];

Example of usage
sol11 = sol[2, 1.5];

lstA = Table[{{xgrid[[i]], t}, vA[[i]]} /. sol11, {i, 
   Length[xgrid]}, {t, 0, 1, .02}]; a = 
 Interpolation[Flatten[lstA, 1]]; lstU = 
 Table[{{xgrid[[i]] , t}, vU[[i]]} /. sol11, {i, Length[xgrid]}, {t, 
   0, 1, .02}]; u = Interpolation[Flatten[lstU, 1]];

x0[t_] = L[t] /. sol11; xmax = x0[1];

{DensityPlot[
  If[x <= x0[t], a[x/x0[t], t], Nothing], {x, 0, xmax}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}, PlotLabel -> "a", PlotPoints -> 100], 
 DensityPlot[
  If[x <= x0[t], u[x/x0[t], t], Nothing], {x, 0, xmax}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}, PlotLabel -> "u", PlotPoints -> 100], 
 Plot[L[t] /. sol11, {t, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "L"}]}


Update 2. We can also implement LDG method described by Ulrich Neumann as follows
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

mesh = ToElementMesh[Line[{{0}, {1}}], "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1/10, 
   "MeshOrder" -> 1];
rand = MeshCells[MeshRegion[mesh], 1][[All, 1]]; (*integration range*)

yi = pi = mesh["Coordinates"] // Flatten; (*y-grid*)
\[Phi]i = 
  Map[ElementMeshInterpolation[mesh, #] &, IdentityMatrix[Length[yi]]];
\[Phi] = Through[\[Phi]i[y]];
\[Phi]y = Map[Derivative[1][#][y] &, \[Phi]i];

ui = Table[u[i][t], {i, 0, Length[yi] - 1}]; (*node values u*)
ai = Table[a[i][t], {i, 0, Length[yi] - 1}]; (*node values a*)
integralGauss1D[rand_, 
  funktion_] :=(*rand besteht aus Indexpaaren des Randes*)
 Block[{w0 = 8/18, w1 = 5/18, gt = 1/2, 
   gdt = Sqrt[3/5]/2,(*Gausspunkte tt-dtt,tt,tt+dtt*)x0, x1, x2, p1, 
   p2}, Total@
    Map[({p1, p2} = pi[[#]];(*Punkte Randelement*)(*3Gausspunkte*)
       x0 = (1 - gt)  p1 + gt  p2;
       x1 = (1 - (gt - gdt))  p1 + (gt - gdt)  p2;
       x2 = (1 - (gt + gdt))  p1 + (gt + gdt)  p2;
       Norm[
         p2 - p1](*Sehnenlänge*) (funktion[x1]  w1 + 
          funktion[x0]  w0 + funktion[x2]  w1)) &, rand](*//
   Rationalize[#,0]&*)/. 0. -> 0]
(*galerkin method*)

ode1 = L[
     t]  integralGauss1D[rand, 
      Function[{y}, Evaluate@Outer[Times, \[Phi], \[Phi]]]] . 
     D[ai, t] - 
   L'[t]  integralGauss1D[rand, 
      Function[{y}, Evaluate@Outer[Times, y  \[Phi], \[Phi]y]]] . ai +
    integralGauss1D[rand, 
    Function[{y}, 
     Evaluate[\[Phi]  ai . \[Phi]y  ui . \[Phi] + \[Phi]  ai . \[Phi] \
 ui . \[Phi]y]]];

neumann[m_] := -m  \[Phi]  ai . \[Phi]  ui . \[Phi]y /. y -> 0 /. 
   0. -> 0;
ode2[m_] := 
  integralGauss1D[rand, 
    Function[{y}, Evaluate[\[Phi]  ai . \[Phi]y  ui . \[Phi]y]]] - 
   neumann[m] - 
   m   integralGauss1D[rand, 
     Function[{y}, 
      Evaluate[\[Phi]y  ai . \[Phi]  ui . \[Phi]y + \[Phi]  ai . \
\[Phi]y  ui . \[Phi]y]]];

ode3 = {L'[t] - ui[[-1]]};
(*solution*)
eqs[m_] := Join[Drop[ode1, -1], Drop[ode2[m], 1], ode3];

sol[m_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := 
 NDSolve[{Table[eqs[m][[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqs[m]]}], 
   Join[{ui[[1]] == Exp[-t], L[0] == 5, ai[[-1]] == 0}, 
    Thread[(ai . \[Phi] /. y -> #) == (L[0] (1 - #))^b & /@ yi] /. 
     t -> 0]}, Join[ai, ui, {L[t]}], {t, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic}];

Example of usage
s11 = sol[1, 1]

LDG solution s11 could be compared with FDM solution sol11 in one plot as
Plot[{L[t]/.sol11, L[t]/.s11}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashed}, {Gray}}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"LDG", "FDM"}]



Thank you for your very nice suggestion. Could you please add a bit more explanation about the first equation you used? Shouldn't the negative sign be positive? Also, why does the time derivative term produce two terms?

Also, is there any way of using your code for other values of m, such as m=0.5 and m=1.5? The initial conditions are not restricted, so initial value for u and a could be other things

@questionerno8 To answer first question evaluate D[a[x/L[t], t], t]. To answer second question, please, explain your model little bit. Why you use $u_x^m$, and not $|u_x|^{m-1} u_x$?

It is $|u_x|^{m-1} u_x$ which I assumed the absolute value is positive and simplified it. But you are right that this could be misleading so I modified the equations.

@AlexTrounev Very clever solution idea from you! I tried a solution with Galerkin method, actual without success. It is probably because the algebraic equations for u (following from second pde) are overdetermined (Mathematica message).  Any idea how to solve this problem? Thanks!

@questionerno8 See update to my answer for a general case of $u_x<0, m\ne 1$. Unfortunately, I can't find initial data for a case $m<1$.

@UlrichNeumann Could you upload your code to see how we can improve it?

@AlexTrounev Thanks , I uploaded my code

@AlexTrounev Thank you veryvery much for your assistance to make FEM-approach run. I didn't realize the parameter dependency neumann[m], ode2[m]. What is your reasoning for omitting two of the equations Drop[ode1, -1], Drop[ode2[m], 1]?

@UlrichNeumann In your code these two dropped equations replaced with two boundary conditions.

@AlexTrounev Thanks. It seemed rather arbitrary to me, have to think about...

Is it possible to sole this for $m \neq 1$ and $u_x>0$?

Also, I think there must be an error somewhere.  In your first code for $u_x>0$, when I use $a(0,t)=L(0)^b$ instead of $a(L(t),t)=0$,  and then plot the solution a(0,t), this is not a constant and increases with t! This is inconsistent with the boundary condition I chose.

@questionerno8 I don't understand, where in my code you see boundary condition $a(0,t)=L(0)^b$? I used in all codes $a(L(t),t)=0$ only, and in the density plot we see that $a(L(t),t)=0$.

Sorry if I wasn't clear. I substituted ((),)=0 with (0,)=(0)^b, but the solution does not satisfy (0,)=(0)^ @AlexTrounev

is there anyway I could use $(0,)=(0)^$ instead of ((),)=0 ?@AlexTrounev

@questionerno8 Actually $a(0,0)=L(0)^b$ is an initial condition. Your question is not to me. I only did code for your model stated in your post.  But if you try to modifier the model with a new boundary conditions, then you can ask a new question since this post can't be extended too much.

I just asked a new question. I appreciate your help if you know how to do this. https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/302393/solving-coupled-quasi-linear-pde-with-boundary-conditions @AlexTrounev

@AlexTrounev do you think it's possible to use a trick to use the same method to solve it?

Not an answer, only code example for discussion of alternative solution approach  using Galerkin method:
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

mesh = ToElementMesh[Line[{{0}, {1}}], "MaxCellMeasure" -> 1/10 ,"MeshOrder" -> 1]  
rand = MeshCells[MeshRegion[mesh], 1][[All, 1]]; (*integration range*)

yi = pi = mesh["Coordinates"] // Flatten; (* y-grid *)
\[Phi]i =Map[ElementMeshInterpolation[mesh, #]&,IdentityMatrix[Length[yi]]];
\[Phi] = Through[\[Phi]i[y]];
\[Phi]y = Map[Derivative[1 ][#][ y] &, \[Phi]i]  ;

ui = Table[u[i][t], {i, 0, Length[yi] - 1}]; (* node values u*)
ai = Table[a[i][t], {i, 0, Length[yi] - 1}]; (* node values a*)

With A[y,t]=ai.\[Phi] and U[y,t]==ui.\[Phi] we try to solve the transformed equations (see Alex Trounev's answer)
$\begin{array}{l}
 -\frac{y L'(t) A^{(1,0)}(y,t)}{L(t)}+\frac{A^{(1,0)}(y,t) U(y,t)+A(y,t)
   U^{(1,0)}(y,t)}{L(t)}+A^{(0,1)}(y,t)=0 \\
 A^{(1,0)}(y,t) U^{(1,0)}(y,t)^m+m A(y,t) U^{(2,0)}(y,t) U^{(1,0)}(y,t)^{m-1}=0 \\
 L'(t)=U(1,t) \\
 U(0,t)=e^{-t} \\
 A(y,0)=(L(0)-L(0) y)^b \\
 A(1,t)=0 \\
 L(0)=5 \\
\end{array}$
For Galerkin method we need Gauss integration routine
integralGauss1D[rand_, 
  funktion_] := (*rand besteht aus Indexpaaren des Randes *)
 Block[{w0 = 8/18, w1 = 5/18, gt = 1/2, 
   gdt = Sqrt[3/5]/2,(*Gausspunkte tt-dtt,tt,tt+dtt*)
   x0, x1, x2 , p1, p2},
  Total@Map[( 
       {p1, p2} = pi[[# ]];(*Punkte Randelement*)
        (* 3Gausspunkte*)
        x0  = (1 - gt) p1 + gt p2;
        x1  = (1 - (gt - gdt )) p1 + (gt - gdt ) p2;
        x2 = (1 - (gt + gdt)) p1 + (gt + gdt) p2;
       Norm[p2 - p1](* 
        Sehnenlänge*)(funktion[x1] w1 + funktion[x0] w0 + 
          funktion[x2] w1) ) &, rand ](*//Rationalize[#,0]&*)/. 0. -> 0
  ]

galerkin method
    ode1 = L[t] integralGauss1D[ rand  , 
      Function[{  y}, Evaluate@ Outer[Times, \[Phi], \[Phi]]]] . 
     D[ai , t] -
   L'[t] integralGauss1D[ rand  , 
      Function[{  y}, Evaluate@ Outer[Times, y \[Phi], \[Phi]y]]] . 
     ai +
   integralGauss1D[ rand  , 
    Function[{  y}, 
     Evaluate [\[Phi] ai . \[Phi]y ui . \[Phi] + \[Phi] ai . \[Phi] \
ui . \[Phi]y ]]] ;
    
neumann = -m \[Phi] ai . \[Phi] ui . \[Phi]y /. y -> 0 /. 0. -> 0;
ode2 = integralGauss1D[ rand  , 
    Function[{  y}, Evaluate[\[Phi] ai . \[Phi]y ui . \[Phi]y]]] - 
   neumann -
   m  integralGauss1D[ rand  , 
     Function[{  y}, 
      Evaluate[\[Phi]y ai . \[Phi] ui . \[Phi]y + \[Phi] ai . \[Phi]y \
ui . \[Phi]y]]];

ode3 = {L'[t] - ui[[-1]]}

solution
sol[m_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ] := 
 NDSolve[{Map[0 == # &, Join[ode1, ode2, ode3]], 
   Join[{ ui[[1]] == Exp[-t], L[0] == 5(*,ai[[-1]]\[Equal]0*)} , 
    Simplify[
     Map[ai . \[Phi] == (L[0] (1 - y))^b /. y -> # &, yi] /. 0. -> 0, 
     b > 0]]}, Join[ai, ui, {L[t]}], {t, 0, 1}, 
  Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic}]

Unfortunately solution gives error message
sol[1, 1]

"NDSolve::overdet: There are fewer dependent variables, {L[t],a[0][t],a[1][t],a[2][t],a[3][t],a[4][t],a[5][t],a[6][t],a[7][t],a[8][t],<<13>>}, than equations, so the system is overdetermined."
It looks like the algebraic equations ode2 and   boundary condition U[0,t]==Exp[-t] are the reason.
Any ideas how to make this approach work?

Please, see Update 2 to my answer :)

By simplifying I get
$$ \partial_t a +u  \partial_x a +a \ \partial_x u =0 $$
$$   m \  a \partial_{x,x} u  +\partial_x a \partial_x u =0 $$
I suspect a moving boundary L. It is not given, I use a fixed L at L=5
 NDSolve[{D[a[x, t], t] + D[a[x, t], x]*u[x, t] + a[x, t]*D[u[x, t], x]==0,
            D[a[x, t], x]*D[u[x, t], x] + 7*a[x, t]*D[u[x, t], x, x] ==0, 
           u[0, t] == E^(-t), a[x, 0] == (5 - x)^2, a[5, t] == 0},
      {a[x, t], u[x, t]}, {x, 0, 5}, {t, 0, 5}]

yielding interpolating functions. How to implement a general moving boundary L(t)? No idea.

The velocity of the moving boundary is given by the boundary value of $u$. Is it possible to somehow account for that?

Is it be possible to account for the moving boundary in a for loop?
