Solving coupled quasi-linear PDEs with boundary conditions
I realized that in this solution, changing one of the boundary conditions makes the answer invalid. I wonder if it is possible to modify the code in this answer to solve the following equations.
$$ \partial_t a(x,t) + \partial_x (a(x,t) u(x,t))=0  $$
$$ \partial_x (a(x,t) |u_x|^{m-1} u_x)=0$$
Initial and boundary conditions are
$$ u(0,t)= exp(-t), $$
$$  a(x,0)= (L_0-x)^b , L_0=L(t=0)=5;  $$
$$ a(0,t)= (L_0)^b, $$
$$ u(L(t),t)= \partial_t L(t)$$
$m$ is a positive real number.
values of $b>0$ and $m$ are arbitrary. In particular $m$ is non-integer.
Edit:
This has now been solved nicely by Alex Trounev. Unfortunately, these initial conditions lead to a not-so-interesting solution $u=u(t)$. A more interesting case would be
$(,0)=(0−)^{(1−/)}$
and
$\partial_x (0,)=−(1−/)(0)^{−/} (−)$
Any ideas on how to solve this? I tried the following but I get an error.
    sol[b_, m_] := Module[{tmax = 1, dy = 1/10}, xgrid = Range[0, 1, dy];
   nn = Length[xgrid];
   M1 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], xgrid, 
      DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
   vA = Table[va[i][t], {i, nn}]; a1 = M1 . vA;
   vU = Table[vu[i][t], {i, nn}]; u1 = M1 . vU;
   mu = RealAbs[u1]^(m - 1);
   eq1 = D[vA, t] - (L'[t]/L[t])  xgrid  a1 + 1/L[t]  M1 . (vA  vU);
   eq1[[1]] = D[vA[[1]], t];
   eq2 = M1 . (vA  mu  u1);
   eq2[[1]] = vU[[1]] - (L[0]^(1 - b/m))  Exp[-t];
   eq3 = {L'[t] - vU[[-1]]};
   ic = Join[vA - (L[0] - L[0]  xgrid)^b /. t -> 0, {L[0] - 5}];
   icb = 
    Join[vU - (L[0] - L[0]  xgrid)^(1 - b/m) /. t -> 0, {L[0] - 5}];
   var = Join[vA, vU, {L[t]}]; eqs = Join[eq1, eq2, eq3];
   s = NDSolve[{Table[eqs[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqs]}], 
      Table[ic[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[ic]}], 
      Table[icb[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[icb]}]}, var, {t, 0, tmax}, 
     Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic}]; s[[1]]];

sol11 = sol[0.5, 2];
lstA = Table[{{xgrid[[i]], t}, vA[[i]]} /. sol11, {i, 
   Length[xgrid]}, {t, 0, 1, .02}]; a = 
 Interpolation[Flatten[lstA, 1]]; lstU = 
 Table[{{xgrid[[i]], t}, vU[[i]]} /. sol11, {i, Length[xgrid]}, {t, 0,
    1, .02}]; u = Interpolation[Flatten[lstU, 1]];

x0[t_] = L[t] /. sol11; xmax = x0[1];

{DensityPlot[
  If[x <= x0[t], a[x/x0[t], t], Nothing], {x, 0, xmax}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}, PlotLabel -> "a", PlotPoints -> 100], 
 DensityPlot[
  If[x <= x0[t], u[x/x0[t], t], Nothing], {x, 0, xmax}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}, PlotLabel -> "u", PlotPoints -> 100], 
 Plot[L[t] /. sol11, {t, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "L"}]}

Now, I have used new code to do this but I still get errors
    sol[b_, m_] := Module[{tmax = 1, dy = 1/10}, xgrid = Range[0, 1, dy];
   nn = Length[xgrid];
   M2 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], xgrid, 
      DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
   M1 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], xgrid, 
      DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
   vA = Table[va[i][t], {i, nn}]; a1 = M1 . vA;
   vU = Table[vu[i][t], {i, nn}]; u1 = M1 . vU;
   mu = RealAbs[u1]^(m - 1);
   eq1 = D[vA, t] - (L'[t]/L[t])  xgrid  a1 + 1/L[t]  M1 . (vA  vU);
   eq1[[1]] = D[vA[[1]], t];
   eq2 = D[M1 . (vA  mu  u1), t];
   eq2[[1]] = D[vU[[1]], t] - (1 - b/m) (L[0])^(-b/m)  Exp[-t];
   eq3 = {L'[t] - vU[[-1]]};
   (*ic=Join[vA-(L[0]-L[0] xgrid)^b/. t->0,{L[0]-5},vU-.1 xgrid/. t->
   0];var=Join[vA,vU,{L[t]}];*)
   ic = Join[vA - (L[0] - L[0]  xgrid)^b /. t -> 0, {L[0] - 5}, 
     vU - (L[0] - L[0]  xgrid)^(1 - b/m) /. t -> 0]; 
   var = Join[vA, vU, {L[t]}];
   eqs = Join[eq1, eq2, eq3];
   s = NDSolve[{Table[eqs[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqs]}], 
      Table[ic[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[ic]}]}, var, {t, 0, tmax}, 
     Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]; s[[1]]];
sol55 = sol[.5, 1.3];

lstA = Table[{{xgrid[[i]], t}, vA[[i]]} /. sol55, {i, 
   Length[xgrid]}, {t, 0, 1, .02}]; a = 
 Interpolation[Flatten[lstA, 1]]; lstU = 
 Table[{{xgrid[[i]], t}, vU[[i]]} /. sol55, {i, Length[xgrid]}, {t, 0,
    1, .02}]; u = Interpolation[Flatten[lstU, 1]];
x0[t_] = L[t] /. sol55; xmax = FindMaximum[x0[t], {t, .5}][[1]];
{DensityPlot[
  If[x <= x0[t], a[x/x0[t], t], Nothing], {x, 0, xmax}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}, PlotLabel -> "a", PlotPoints -> 100], 
 DensityPlot[
  If[x <= x0[t], u[x/x0[t], t], Nothing], {x, 0, xmax}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}, PlotLabel -> "u", PlotPoints -> 100], 
 Plot[L[t] /. sol55, {t, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "L"}]}


At a minimum, please provide you equations in Mathematica format.  Also, are you seeking a symbolic or numerical solution?  If the latter, please provide the values of all constants.

I have added a comment on this. Thanks for your comment @bbgodfrey

We can solve this problem using FDM code from here with a small modification
sol[b_, m_] := 
  Module[{tmax = 1, dy = 1/10}, xgrid = Range[0, 1, dy]; 
   nn = Length[xgrid];
   M1 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], xgrid, 
      DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
   vA = Table[va[i][t], {i, nn}]; a1 = M1 . vA;
   vU = Table[vu[i][t], {i, nn}]; u1 = M1 . vU; 
   mu = RealAbs[u1]^(m - 1);
   eq1 = D[vA, t] - (L'[t]/L[t]) xgrid a1 + 1/L[t] M1 . (vA vU); 
   eq1[[1]] = D[vA[[1]], t];
   eq2 = M1 . (vA mu u1);
   eq2[[1]] = vU[[1]] - Exp[-t]; eq3 = {L'[t] - vU[[-1]]};
   ic = Join[vA - (L[0] - L[0] xgrid)^b /. t -> 0, {L[0] - 5}]; 
   var = Join[vA, vU, {L[t]}]; eqs = Join[eq1, eq2, eq3]; 
   s = NDSolve[{Table[eqs[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqs]}], 
      Table[ic[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[ic]}]}, var, {t, 0, tmax}, 
     Method -> {"IndexReduction" -> Automatic}]; s[[1]]];

Example of usage
sol11 = sol[2, 2];

Visualization
lstA = Table[{{xgrid[[i]], t}, vA[[i]]} /. sol11, {i, 
   Length[xgrid]}, {t, 0, 1, .02}]; a = 
 Interpolation[Flatten[lstA, 1]]; lstU = 
 Table[{{xgrid[[i]] , t}, vU[[i]]} /. sol11, {i, Length[xgrid]}, {t, 
   0, 1, .02}]; u = Interpolation[Flatten[lstU, 1]];

x0[t_] = L[t] /. sol11; xmax = x0[1];

{DensityPlot[
  If[x <= x0[t], a[x/x0[t], t], Nothing], {x, 0, xmax}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}, PlotLabel -> "a", PlotPoints -> 100], 
 DensityPlot[
  If[x <= x0[t], u[x/x0[t], t], Nothing], {x, 0, xmax}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}, PlotLabel -> "u", PlotPoints -> 100], 
 Plot[L[t] /. sol11, {t, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "L"}]}


Update 1. We can improve code above so that we can add initial data for u[x,t] as well. We have
sol[b_, m_] := 
  Module[{tmax = 1, dy = 1/10}, xgrid = Range[0, 1, dy]; 
   nn = Length[xgrid];
   M2 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[2], xgrid, 
      DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix"; 
   M1 = NDSolve`FiniteDifferenceDerivative[Derivative[1], xgrid, 
      DifferenceOrder -> 4]@"DifferentiationMatrix";
   vA = Table[va[i][t], {i, nn}]; a1 = M1 . vA;
   vU = Table[vu[i][t], {i, nn}]; u1 = M1 . vU; 
   mu = RealAbs[u1]^(m - 1);
   eq1 = D[vA, t] - (L'[t]/L[t]) xgrid a1 + 1/L[t] M1 . (vA vU); 
   eq1[[-1]] = D[vA[[-1]], t];
   eq2 = D[M1 . (vA mu u1), t];
   eq2[[1]] = D[vU[[1]], t] + Exp[-t]; eq3 = {L'[t] - vU[[-1]]};
   ic = Join[vA - (L[0] - L[0] xgrid)^b /. t -> 0, {L[0] - 5}, 
     vU - .1 xgrid /. t -> 0]; var = Join[vA, vU, {L[t]}]; 
   eqs = Join[eq1, eq2, eq3]; 
   s = NDSolve[{Table[eqs[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[eqs]}], 
      Table[ic[[i]] == 0, {i, Length[ic]}]}, var, {t, 0, tmax}, 
     Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]; s[[1]]];

Example of usage
sol55 = sol[.5, .5];

lstA = Table[{{xgrid[[i]], t}, vA[[i]]} /. sol55, {i, 
   Length[xgrid]}, {t, 0, 1, .02}]; a = 
 Interpolation[Flatten[lstA, 1]]; lstU = 
 Table[{{xgrid[[i]] , t}, vU[[i]]} /. sol55, {i, Length[xgrid]}, {t, 
   0, 1, .02}]; u = Interpolation[Flatten[lstU, 1]];
x0[t_] = L[t] /. sol55; xmax = FindMaximum[x0[t], {t, .5}][[1]];
{DensityPlot[
  If[x <= x0[t], a[x/x0[t], t], Nothing], {x, 0, xmax}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}, PlotLabel -> "a", PlotPoints -> 100], 
 DensityPlot[
  If[x <= x0[t], u[x/x0[t], t], Nothing], {x, 0, xmax}, {t, 0, 1}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "t"}, PlotLabel -> "u", PlotPoints -> 100], 
 Plot[L[t] /. sol11, {t, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "L"}]}



Thanks for your help. I think there might be an issue with this method as it gives a solution in which u only depends on t and not on x! This can be seen by plotting Animate[Plot[u[x/x0[t], t], {x, 0, xmax},
PlotRange -> {{0, 16}, {0, 1}}], {t, 0, 1}] . This is probably why the code doesn't work for m<1 as in this case $1/ \partial_x u$ goes to infinity. Any idea how to solve this?

@questionerno8 No it not right. Please check picture in my answer. There are clearly seen that a depends on x and t as well. :)

Sorry, my last comment was wrong but still, the first one is correct and the solution gives u=u(t) and is independent of x. this is not very interesting as one could solve the equations analytically in this case. I think this might be resolved by using $$  \partial_x u(0,t)= exp(-t), $$. Is it possible to use this boundary condition and see if it gives u to be a function of x as well?

Equations have first order derivative of x, but why doesn't that allow us to use $\partial_x u(x_0,t) =exp(-t)$ at x_0=0?

To make it work we can assume that $u(x,0)= (L_0-x)^{(1-b/m)}$ and $\partial_x u(0,t)=-(1-b/m) (L_0)^{-b/m} exp(-t)$ . Is there any chance these could be used?

I added the following lines eq2[[1]] =
vU[[1]] - (L[0]^{1 - b/m}) Exp[-t]; eq3 = {L'[t] - vU[[-1]]};
ic = Join[vA - (L[0] - L[0]  xgrid)^b /. t -> 0, {L[0] - 5}];
icb = Join[vU - (L[0] - L[0]  xgrid)^{1 - b/m} /. t -> 0, {L[0] - 5}];                                      but I get an error!

@questionerno8 I see that you modified your question, while it has been answered. Now my answer looks like a wrong one.  Could you stop doing such modification? Instead you can add new question to your old one.

I edited it back to the previous version. I just think this is more interesting.

I did not mean to make your advanced code look wrong, was just trying to make it give a non-trivial answer

Could you have a look at the code I added to the question?

@questionerno8 Thank you for the new edition of your question. I see your point. We can try to solve this problem without NDSolve using FDM code only.

Would it be possible for you add how to do this without NDSolve in your answer?

When I comment out NDSolve, I still get errors. Could you please clarify what you mean?

Hi, when I use the code for large values of tmax, the output becomes extremely large (10^23). This is apparently non-physical. Is there any reason for that? How can I avoid this.

@questionerno8 Please, see Update 1 to my code with initial data for u[x,t] and for m=0.5, b=0.5.

Thanks. This is however very different from the question in Edit. I have tried to use your new method according to edit and I get errors. Could you please see my code that I just added to the question?

I think this line in your latest edit is wrong 'eq2[[1]] = D[vU[[1]], t] + Exp[-t];' The boundary condition in the question has derivative respect to 'x' and nit 'y'

@questionerno8 It is not wrong, it is model what we can suggest you to use since it is working for m<1 as well.

Sorry but the following line in your edit is wrong $eq2 = D[M1 . (vA mu u1), t];$. Time derivative is not zero. I can't see where you got that equation from.

@questionerno8 Actually this follows from your equation $\partial_x (a(x,t) |u_x|^{m-1} u_x)=0$ that $\partial_t (\partial_x (a(x,t) |u_x|^{m-1} u_x))=0$. Please, not, that this is used not as equation himself, but just as numerical trick to solve system of DAEs with NDSolve.

This is not correct. For a general form $ |_x|^{−1} _=()$
. and $\partial_t ()≠0$

@questionerno8 Sorry, but you a wrong from the beginning, since if some function $F(x,t)=0$ everywhere, then $\partial_t F=0$ as well. So if  $F=\partial_x (a(x,t) |u_x|^{m-1} u_x)=0$ then  $\partial_t F=0$  :).

That is not true. a function $f(t)$ is not zero, it just does not have any x dependency.

@questionerno8 You are wrong about $F$, not about $f$, also please pay attention that $F$ nothing to do with $f$ :)

Oh, I see now! Could you please explain what this line means? eq2[[1]] = D[vU[[1]], t] + Exp[-t]; ? Is it equivalent to $\partial_x u(0,t)=exp(-t)$?

The trick sounds interesting!

@questionerno8 Yes it is, eq2 is also trick with  $\partial_x u(0,t)-e^{-t}$.
